# Able to ssh to EC2 via Cyberduck, but unable to ssh via Terminal using same credentials

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, terminal, ssh-keys

I'm able to SSH / SFTP into an EC2 instance using Cyberduck with Public Key Authentication. However, I'm unable to ssh in via Terminal with the same username, server, port and PEM credential. This is the ssh command I'm attempting:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-pem.pem username@server-ip

In response, I get the OS X dialog "Enter your password for the SSH key 'my-pem.pem'". My OS X user password does not work and there doesn't appear to be a password on the PEM since Cyberduck does not require one. When I cancel out of the dialog, the terminal response is "Permission denied (publickey)." Things to note:

- Perms on my-pem.pem are 600.
- Perms on the ~/.ssh/ directory are 700.
- The username is not ec2-user
- I tried clearing out my .bash_profile to rule out anything strange
- I'm running OS X 10.10
- "which ssh" produces "/usr/bin/ssh"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Upon adding the verbose (-v) option to ssh, I discovered the issues was with the format of my certificate. I copied the contents of the certificate to a new file in my text editor and that certificate worked. Strange as both files are UTF-8 encoded with identical contents and perms.